# Docker networking cannot connect to local IP in Container

Tags: docker, networking, apache-kafka

Bit of a newb when it comes to networking...

- I have a Kafka cluster (1 master and 1 worker) running on 2 Vbox VMs on my laptop using Docker Swarm. This VM has a bridge adapter that is set to single IP address. The exact YAML is

```
enp0s8:
      dhcp4: no
      renderer: networkd
      addresses: [192.168.0.50/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

- I try to run a local Python script which connects to my Kafka cluster. This works when I do it on my laptop, however when I run the same Python script in a Docker container, it does not work!

This pretty much narrows it down to a networking issue. I have tried running the container using `--net=host` and it still doesn't work. Confused as to why my Docker container cannot connect to the IP address of the VM but locally on my macbook it runs fine.

Edit:

To give further clarifications on the Python script...
The entire script is here:

```
from kafka.consumer import KafkaConsumer

def create_kafka_consumer(topic, group_id, brokers):
    return KafkaConsumer(topic,
                         bootstrap_servers=brokers,
                         auto_offset_reset='earliest',
                         enable_auto_commit=True,
                         group_id=group_id,
                         value_deserializer=lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'))

GROUP_ID = 'test'
def main():
    topic ='airbnb'
    c = create_kafka_consumer(topic, 'tester', '192.168.0.51:9093')
    for msg in c:
        print(msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The IP address and port is for the Kafka WORKER node (which is running in the Virtual Box), not master node (IP address listed above). I set the IP in the VM and the port was manually set in the docker-compose file.

Successful output example (just prints all the kafka logs):

> ConsumerRecord(topic='airbnb', partition=0, offset=169, timestamp=1598650807052, timestamp_type=0, key=None, value='adivinen quien cogio un airbnb para salir de la rutina y tiene que trabajar el weekend? ', headers=[], checksum=None, serialized_key_size=-1, serialized_value_size=111, serialized_header_size=-1)
> ConsumerRecord(topic='airbnb', partition=0, offset=170, timestamp=1598650821359, timestamp_type=0, key=None, value='This x100%', headers=[], checksum=None, serialized_key_size=-1, serialized_value_size=10, serialized_header_size=-1)

Unsuccessful output:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "tmp/consumer-kafka.py", line 21, in 
> main()
> File "tmp/consumer-kafka.py", line 16, in main
> c = create_kafka_consumer(topic, 'tester', '192.168.0.51:9093')
> File "tmp/consumer-kafka.py", line 11, in create_kafka_consumer
> value_deserializer=lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'))
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/consumer/group.py", line 355, in **init**
> self._client = KafkaClient(metrics=self._metrics, **self.config)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 242, in **init**
> self.config['api_version'] = self.check_version(timeout=check_timeout)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 925, in check_version
> raise Errors.NoBrokersAvailable()
> kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable

The Kafka worker `netstat -ntl` command output:
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what OS you are using? Also just to reiterate, you are trying to connect your docker container where your python script resides to the VirtualBox kafka cluster; is that correct?

Comment: In addition to the above, it would be helpful to see the commands run and the outputs (including errors). Also, can you show the output of `ss -ntl` or `netstat -ntl` so we can see the Kafka listening socket? Usually, if you are running Docker for Mac or Docker for Windows you could access services on the host from containers at `host.docker.internal`.

Comment: Why not run Kafka in a container? Also, depending on host OS, containers run in their own VM anyway

Comment: @khariSeeng - Mac OSx Mojave. Yup, container with script is trying to connect to Vbox Kafka Cluster (kafka is also running on a docker swarm in the vbox).

Comment: @AndyShinn - I'll add more details to the question for this

Comment: @OneCricketeer - Forgot to clarify that Kafka is running in a container on the Vbox. While true, the purpose of this project is to emulate a cloud deployment.

Comment: Swarm? How many VMs do you have? Personally, I would use k8s if you want to emulate a cloud deployment or just use Confluent Cloud to start with

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with -- link option to communicate with 2 containers while running docker container this will add an entry in /etc/hosts file (or you can try it manually and check)

I think this may help you: https://docs.docker.com/network/links/

youtube: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=docker+linking+multiple+containers

if both doesn't suits your fit research with some DNS in docker this might be DNS related :-)